# CMS Log in problem

Tags: 2011, ldap

I am having problem in log on to CMS, On my Tridion server I can log in using administrator account (it is not a domain account, it is local administrator account), I can browse publications but when I click on "Structure Group" or any other item in tree, it shows "Loading" but never loads anything, If I hit browser refresh, it loads successfully but again if I click on any other item in the tree I see "Loading" again.

Second problem is that I can't log on to CMS from another compueter using my domain group account, I get following exception:

Unable to Initialize TDSE object. Binding to LDAP server (my domain here)
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential,Boolean) Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.GetLdapSearchConnection() Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.GetLdapSearchConnection() Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.GetUser(String) Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,String) Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String,String,UserContext) Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.InitializeUserContext(UserContext,String,String) UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext TDSE.Initialize

Comment: Do you think this could be a clue: Binding to LDAP server (my domain here) ?

Comment: yes could be, from error it looks like LDAP is not connect able but I can ping my domain name, I have downloaded and installed AD Explorer tool and I can connect to my domain, where should i look into?

Comment: Is it like your CMS is configured to authenticate against an LDAP server and you are trying to use the AD users? In case youo are using LDAP (as it looks like) Are you sure your user is created in the LDAP directory and also has been marked as enabled. Further this LDAP user must also be added in the CMS. Check all this and update

Comment: CMS is configured to authenticate against LDAP and i have checked all users are added in CMS with administrator access. It was all working fine, Tridion license got expired 2 weeks ago and we have managed to get an "Emergency" license for 1 month, after applying license things were working but suddenly may be a week ago we started facing log in issue, I can still access CMS with administrator login which is not a domain account.

Comment: A new team member joined us a week ago and I have added his account in CMS but now if I try to add or search user I get "The supplied credentials is invalid" message.